# Rails has_one and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

How come when I change my `user.rb` model to the correct way of `has_one :student` instead of `has_many :students` it breaks student controller in my `Create` method and says that 'new' is an undefined method?

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :vehicle
  has_one :permit
  has_one :faculty
  has_one :emergency_contact
  has_one :student
end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to    :user
  has_one   :emergency_contact
  has_one   :vehicle 
end
```

students_controller.rb

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
.....
def create
@student = current_user.student.new(student_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @student.save
    format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully 
    created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: 
    :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

I am trying to pass in the current user ID who is logged in using the Devise current_user method and assign it to the student. It works when I change in the user model from `has_one :student` to `has_many :students`, and when I change the students controller from `current_user.student.new()` to `current_user.students.new()` but that is not correct, because the user has only one student. I am just really lost how I am breaking it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference), the `has_one` association does not have a `new` method.  Try using `build_student()` instead.  In your case, this should work:

```
def create
  @student = current_user.build_student(student_params)
  ...
end
```

Comment: That was it, I was trying to figure out if it didn't exist but couldn't find it! Thank you very much!